# how to keep the controller context to it's view?

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, ember.js, javascript

I have started learning ember just 2 days back.

I have been creating calculator app using ember. Now I have created different module for button and calculator. After attaching the button view to calculator view, I am trying to handle the click of button. When clicking the button, the buttonController function is not getting called. Below is the code implemented by me so far.

**ButtonView**

```
Calculator.ButtonView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName : "button",
    controllerBinding : "Calculator.ButtonController",
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("{{view.content}}"),
    click : function(e) {
      var keyClicked = $(e.target).closest('button');
      var key = $(keyClicked).text();
      this.set('controller.key',key);
      this.get('controller').keyPressed();
    }
});
```

**ButtonController**

```
Calculator.ButtonController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    key : null,
    keyPressed : function(){
        alert(this.key);
    }.observes('key')
 });
```

**CalculatorView**

```
Calculator.CalculatorView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
    childViews: ['screenView', 'keysView'],
    screenView : Calculator.ScreenView.extend({
        displayText : "",
        classNames : ['display']
    }),
    keysView : Ember.ContainerView.extend({
        childViews:['numberKeysView','operatorKeysView'],
        classNames : ['buttons'],
        numberKeysView : Ember.CollectionView.extend({
            classNames : ['number'],
            content : ['7','8','9','4','5','6','1','2','3','0'],
            itemViewClass : Calculator.ButtonView.extend()
        }),
        operatorKeysView : Ember.CollectionView.extend({
            classNames : ['operator'],
            content : ['+','-','*','/','=','C'],
            itemViewClass : Calculator.ButtonView.extend()
        })
    })

});
```

When I click then error is coming in click function saying that function is not defined. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Putting your code in JSBin would help everyone understand & resolve your issues faster.

I would write the click functionality in Controller (using actions) rather than view, bind it to my button (in template/hbs file).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**ButtonView**

```
Calculator.ButtonView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName : "button",
    controllerBinding : "Calculator.ButtonController",
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("{{view.content}}"),
    click : function(e) {
      var keyClicked = $(e.target).closest('button');
      var key = $(keyClicked).text();
      this.set('controller.key',key);
      this.get('controller').keyPressed();
    }
});
```

In the above piece of code there is no need to call keyPressed() explicity as you have put it as an observer it would fire automatically.

Secondly this is not the ember way of handling what you are trying to do. Your approach should be something like this.

1. In your template you should be doing somehthing like this.) 
   `<div {{action 'buttonClicked'}}>{{view.content}}</div>`.
2. Now catch that action in the controller this view is bound to.

   `Calculator.ButtonController = Ember.Controller.extend({
       keySet:(function(){
                 //do actions that you want to do when a key is set.
       }).observes("key"),
       actions : {
           buttonClicked:function(e){
           //handle button click in this function.
           //this.set("key",key)
           }
       }
    })`